# bash redirection to files not working

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, cat, uniq

I have this two files, `yolo.txt` and `bar.txt`:

yolo.txt:

```
a
b
c
```

bar.txt:

```
c
```

I have the following command, which gets me the desired output:

```
$ cat yolo.txt bar.txt | sort | uniq -u | sponge
a
b
```

But when I add the redirection (`>`) statement, the output changes:

```
$ cat yolo.txt bar.txt | sort | uniq -u | sponge > yolo.txt && cat yolo.txt
c
```

I expected the output to remain the same, and I am quite confused. Please help me.

Comment: You know about sponge, but you don't know why it's necessary? How did that come about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `> yolo.txt` shell redirect happens before any of the commands run. In particular, the shell opens `yolo.txt` for writing **and truncates it** before executing `cat yolo.txt bar.txt`. So by the time `cat` opens `yolo.txt`, `yolo.txt` is empty. Therefore the `c` line in `bar.txt` is unique, so `uniq -u` passes it through.

I guess you wanted to use `sponge` to avoid this problem, since that's what `sponge` is for. But you used it incorrectly. This is the correct usage:

```
cat yolo.txt bar.txt | sort | uniq -u | sponge yolo.txt && cat yolo.txt
```

Note that I just pass the output filename to `sponge` as a command-line argument, instead of using a shell redirect.